# How do I go about making a looping canvas background for a game in just plain javascript?

Tags: java, html, 2d-games

This is making me crazy lol. I'm making a simple side runner game and want to make grass in the background zoom by real fast in a loop(the grass is a sprite that stretches the width of the canvas). I under stand how to implement all the sprite functions I need but I just can't seem to get this detail working. I'm trying to just use basic JavaScript. Any ideas would be greatly greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

### Endlessly scrolling repeating images

To draw an endless scrolling background you need a repeating image.

An example repeating grass image 256 by 72 px as used in basic demos below.

[image]

When you move the image sideways when it has moved a distance equal to its width you move it in the opposite direction by the same width.

This can most easily be done using the remainder operator `%`

```
const worldSpeed = -20;  // images moves from right to left
var w = image.width;
var worldPos = w;
```

Then for each update move the image position and draw the image

```
worldPos = ((worldPos + worldSpeed) % w + w) % w;
ctx.drawImage(image, worldPos, ctx.canvas.height - image.height);
```

It is likely that the image will not be wide enough to cover the whole width of the display. To solve just repeat the image by drawing copies to the right and left so that they always cover all the display  (or using a pattern)

### Endless scroll demo

- The example shows the grass texture as an endless scroll.
- The image is drawn 3 times to fit across the canvas.
- With keyboard and mouse click canvas to focus and the use left and right arrows to move.
- Without keyboard wait 5 second and it will start.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
const W = canvas.width, H = canvas.height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const grass = new Image;
grass.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8GdJ.png";
const sky = new Image;
sky.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfmBf.png";
const maxSpeed = 100;
var worldPos = 0, speed = 0, acceleration = 0.5;
var skyPos = 0

function drawImageRepeat(x, img) {
    const ih = img.naturalHeight
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, H - ih);
    ctx.drawImage(img, x + 256, H - ih);
    ctx.drawImage(img, x - 256, H - ih);
}

function move() {
    if (grass.complete && sky.complete) {
        if (keys.left) { speed-= acceleration }
        if (keys.right) { speed+= acceleration }
        speed = speed< -maxSpeed ? -maxSpeed : speed > maxSpeed ? maxSpeed : speed;
        speed *= 0.99;
        worldPos = ((worldPos + speed) % 256 + 256) % 256;   
        skyPos = ((skyPos + speed / 16) % 256 + 256) % 256; 
        drawImageRepeat(skyPos, sky);
        drawImageRepeat(worldPos, grass);
    }
}
function renderLoop() {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
    move();
    speed  && (info.textContent = "Speed: " + (speed * 60).toFixed(0) + "Px per second");
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}


const K = {ArrowLeft: "left", ArrowRight: "right"};
const keys = {left: false, right: false};
const listen = (cb, ...ns) => ns.forEach(n => addEventListener(n, cb));
const keyEvent = (e, n = K[e.code]) => n && (keys[n] = (e.preventDefault(), e.type === "keydown")); 
listen(keyEvent, "keydown", "keyup");
setTimeout(() => speed === 0 && (keys.left = true), 5000);
```

```css
#info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 24;
}
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div id="info">Click to focuse then Left Right Arrow keys to move</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="150"></canvas>
```

### Problem

When the speed starts to get very high the scrolling image does not look natural, it can even start to look like its slowing down if allowed to continue accelerating.

### Motion blur

To avoid this effect we need to introduce some motion blur.

The following demo is the same as above but rather than draw the repeated image once per frame it is draw once for each pixel it moved between frames. Eg if the speed is 100 px per frame it will be draw 100 time moved 1 pixel per draw.

The amount of the image that must contribute to each step (if speed is 100 px per frame) will be about 100th. We use alpha to reduce the amount the image adds per frame.

There are some other problems with this method that the demo overcomes by changing the spread of the blur and stopping it when it gets to slow.

#### Motion blur demo

**Note** the sky does not have motion blur applied.

```js
const W = canvas.width, H = canvas.height;
requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const grass = new Image;
grass.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8GdJ.png";
const sky = new Image;
sky.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfmBf.png";

const maxSpeed = 100;
var worldPos = 256, skyPos = 256, speed = 0, acceleration = 0.5

function drawImageRepeat(x, img) {
    const ih = img.naturalHeight
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, H - ih);
    ctx.drawImage(img, x + 256, H - ih);
    ctx.drawImage(img, x - 256, H - ih);
}

function move() {
    if (grass.complete && sky.complete) {
        if (keys.left) { speed -= acceleration }
        if (keys.right) { speed += acceleration }
        speed = speed < -maxSpeed ? -maxSpeed : speed > maxSpeed ? maxSpeed : speed;
        speed *= 0.99;
        worldPos = ((worldPos + speed) % 256 + 256) % 256;
        skyPos = ((skyPos + speed / 16) % 256 + 256) % 256; 
        var dir = Math.sign(speed);
        var i = Math.abs(speed) + 1 | 0;
        drawImageRepeat(skyPos, sky);
        if (i < 2) {
            drawImageRepeat(worldPos, grass);
        } else {
            if (i < 20) {
                ctx.globalAlpha = 1 - (i / 20);
                dir *= i / 20;
                drawImageRepeat((worldPos + i * dir) % 256, grass);
            }
            ctx.globalAlpha = (1 / i) ** 0.95;
            while (i--) { drawImageRepeat((worldPos + i * dir) % 256, grass) }
            ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        }
    }
}
function renderLoop() {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
    move();
    speed && (info.textContent = "Speed: " + (speed * 60).toFixed(0) + "Px per second");
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}
const K = {ArrowLeft: "left", ArrowRight: "right"};
const keys = {left: false, right: false};
const listen = (cb, ...ns) => ns.forEach(n => addEventListener(n, cb));
const keyEvent = (e, n = K[e.code]) => n && (keys[n] = (e.preventDefault(), e.type === "keydown")); 
listen(keyEvent, "keydown", "keyup");
setTimeout(() => speed === 0 && (keys.left = true), 5000);
```

```css
#info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 24;
}
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div id="info">Click to focuse then Left Right Arrow keys to move</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="150"></canvas>
```

#### Very heavy CPU/GPU load

This is obviously very CPU/GPU expensive (at a speed of 100 it needs to draw the image 300 times).

This can be overcome if you render the image with motion blur at several different speeds (using photoshop, blender, or via the canvas using the demo code above)

Then rather than draw the image for each pixel moved, you blend the pre rendered motion blurred images as the speed increases. You then at most need only render each image twice (as you blend from one pre rendered blur to the next) rather than 100s of times.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is with moving the background, you can use CSS.

For example:

```
background_sprite.animate([

    {"left": "0px"},
    {"left": "100px"}

], {

    "duration": 7000 // In milliseconds

})
```

and to make it move faster you can just decrease the duration.
The only downside to this method, is the `left` position is reset after the animation is finished.
This can be bypassed by having a timeout function run asynchronously.
For example:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    background_sprite.style.left = "100px"
}, 7000)
```

So our complete movement code could look something like this

```
background_sprite.animate([
    {"left": "0px"},
    {"left": background_sprite.style.width}
], {
    "duration": 500 // In milliseconds
})
setTimeout(() => {
    background_sprite.style.left = background_sprite.style.width
}, 500)
```

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you!!