# How do I optimize JavaScript Canvas 2d Animation?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Can anyone help me optimize this animation I am trying to make.

Basically a car image sits in the foreground and the background moves behind it so it looks like the car is moving. It's pretty simple but it keeps getting very laggy and crashing.

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function() {
  console.log('Fullscreen Change');
});

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawCar(){
  ctx.drawImage(img, 20, canvas.height-200);
}

const backgroundFrames = [];

let img;
let interval;

let x = 0;

const patternCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const patternContext = patternCanvas.getContext('2d');
patternCanvas.width = 4096;
patternCanvas.height = 700;

    const patImg = new Image();
    patImg.addEventListener('load', function() {
      
      for (let i = 0; i >= -4096; i -= 16){
        patternContext.drawImage(patImg, i, 0);
        let k = i/-16;
        backgroundFrames[k] = ctx.createPattern(patternCanvas, 'repeat-x');
      }
      
      
      img = new Image();
      img.addEventListener('load', function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
          interval = setInterval(bckchg, 1000/30);
        }, 3000);
      }, false);
      img.src = 'img.png';

    }, false);
    patImg.src = 'background.jpg';

let l = 0;

function bckchg(){
  
  ctx.fillStyle = backgroundFrames[l];
  
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  drawCar();
  
  l++;
  
  if(l === 187){
    l = 0;
  }
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(){
  clearInterval(interval);
});
```

I've tried creating all the background images beforehand but its still pretty laggy and still crashes.

I know the code is pretty messy, I only started coding recently. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Here is the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drive</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="drive1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <canvas id="canvas">
      </canvas>
      <!--<img src="background.jpg">-->
      <!--<div id="menu">-->
      <!--  <button id="start">Start</button>-->
      <!--  <button id="stop">Stop</button>-->
      <!--  <input id="volSlider" type="range" name="vol" min="o" max="100">-->
      <!--  <label id="volLabel" for="vol">Volume</label>-->
        
      <!--  <form id="songForm">-->
      <!--    <input type="radio" id="td" name="song" value="td">-->
      <!--    <label for="td">Tokyo Drift</label>-->
      <!--    <br>-->
      <!--    <input type="radio" id="supra" name="song" value="supra">-->
      <!--    <label for="supra">Supra</label>-->
      <!--  </form>-->
  
      <!--</div>-->
    </main>
    <script src="drive_mk2.js">
    </script>
    <script src="drive_music.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't se the original HTML, but instead of `setInterval` you should use `requestAnimationFrame` which waits for next animation frame so animation is smooth. It's pretty much similar syntax but this happens around 60hz so you might want to use some time variable. See my recent answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72821732/3807365

So in your case, change accordingly:

```
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var loop = function() {
      bckchg();
      interval = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    loop();
  }, 3000);
}, false);

// and
canvas.addEventListener('click', function() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(interval);
});
```

Update: No answer about background scroll animation would be complete without a link to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67305637/3807365

Comment: So I used your code here, and it definitely helped, but it still gets laggy after a few seconds and runs way faster at about 60 fps I am guessing until then. I am pretty sure I need a time variable so it doesn't go too fast, any suggestions on how to do that? And also, I have edited my question to include the html.

Comment: You can try instead of `l++` to do `l += 0.1` (and round it for the array index). Ideally you would have increased by `delta_time * car_speed` and not `0.1`  but it might work.

Comment: Yeah, now the page won't even load and if I try and open developer tools it just crashes immediately. I think I may have to head back to the drawing board and try again because for some reason these animations are just way too much for JavaScript to handle, or it might just be my computer. Thank you so much though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for another method for a scrolling background here's something you can try. Create a class for your background and then create 2 instances of it. Once the first background scrolls off the right edge of the screen just set it's `x` back to `canvas.width`.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;

let bg = new Image();
bg.src = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/TUeeuiH2XxHiKzH11POaAM7_K082QIou_0WRW5_LqW1BMAxKjnyTDX1bUju7sawS2o1g0Xp-536vJH0lEnRfE6SM_gBKmU85RAwoMdZhUMDD_WC1wg-FDfHxtzEWyjWixlg1SOZALQ=w2400';

class Background {
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = 0;
    this.w = canvas.width;
    this.h = canvas.height;
    this.vx = 0;
    this.vy = 0;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.drawImage(bg, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h)
  }
  update() {
    this.vx = -2;
    this.x += this.vx;
    if (this.x + this.w <= 1) this.x = canvas.width;
  }
}
let bg1 = new Background(0);
let bg2 = new Background(canvas.width)

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  bg1.draw()
  bg2.draw()
  bg1.update()
  bg2.update()
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
animate()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I got it to work with this method, it's not exactly what I wanted but it's pretty close and I am going to play around with it and see if I can get it to do what I want. Thank you so much.